# How to get class by name in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the string with class name. I want to get a class with this name and call a static methods of this class.

How to make something like this?

```php
$className = "Model";
getClassByName($className)::sayHello();
```

Comment: `$className::sayHello()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the method on the variable, you might want to wrap an "if" around it to check if the class exists.

```php
$className = "Model";
if (class_exists($className)) {
    $className::sayHello();
}
```

You can check out [this 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ufCrm) for a repro case.